# Is there a way to display the text content of a field in PHP?

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

So I have two fields in s template page:

```
<?php echo get_post_field('post_content', 12345); ?>
<?php the_field('advertisement_one', 12345); ?>
```

The first field renders as:

```
<p>
<img src="test.jpg">
</p>
```

The second field renders as:

```
<p>
<img src="test2.jpg">
</p>
```

Is there a way that I can just pull the text content from the "src" in both fields?

My goal is to write/display:

```
test.jpg

or 

test2.jpg
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
<?php
$str = get_post_field('post_content', 12345);
$str = str_replace("\n", '', $str);
$str = str_replace('<p><img src="', '', $str);
$str = str_replace('"></p>', '', $str);
echo $str;
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$content1 = get_post_field('post_content', 12345);
$content2 = get_field('advertisement_one', 12345);
$src1 = preg_replace('|^.+src=["\'](.*)["\'].+$|s','$1',$conten1);
$src2 = preg_replace('|^.+src=["\'](.*)["\'].+$|s','$1',$conten2);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use preg_match to check img tag and fetch its src value

please try this code

```
<?php $value = get_post_field('post_content', 12345); 
$value2 = get_field('advertisement_one', 12345); 

$src1 = preg_match('/< *img[^>]*src *= *["\']?([^"\']*)/i', $value, $matches);
echo $matches[1];

$src2 = preg_match('/< *img[^>]*src *= *["\']?([^"\']*)/i', $value2, $matches);
echo $matches[1];

?>
```